# Google Calendar push notifications. Up to date flag

Tags: push-notification, google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I've subscribed on [google calendar push notifications (PN)](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#making-watch-requests). Base synchronization processes using PN. I need to know if all events already loaded in calendar scope or not.

Is it possible to have a special marker in my request answer (request events for specified calendar based on subscribed channel information)?

---

If calendar has too much events, events will be loaded in few push notifications handling. I need marker for UI if calendar is synchronized completely. In my my usual logic I thought that calendar is already synchronized if first PN per calendar already handled. So I need notify my UI client with correct status (`calendar_is_synchronnized`, `calendar_is_not_synchronnized`) but I do not have any markers from google if the PN provides me load last events portion in specified calendar scope.

Comment: What are you trying to do and what've you tried?

Comment: @noogui, thanks for checking my question. I red it one more time, and I've added under line some more details (this details are not important for getting correct solution, i think, but situation should be pretty clear).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got elegant solution for my question. But I've solved issue with `double call`. The is no special API for this purpose, I've used algorithm:

> after updating to sync token I try get all events for same calendar just to be able compare new `nextSyncToken` with current if it is the same.
>   if token is different if means the calendar sync is not completed yet.

---

If any better idea(s), you are welcome.